# Create a tag / branch from local working copy using SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tagging, command-line-arguments, working-copy

I have a Nant script which updates a directory with the latest source code (checked out from the svn repository), then updates Assembly Info and a few other files and does some builds.

I want the working copy which includes all changes made (after the build is run) be made into a tag revision (described in SVN help 4.19. Branching / Tagging).  This should happen via command line arguments run at the end of the build script.

Currently the following line is used but it will not pick up the changes.

```
svn copy -r 1234 c:\workingCopy http://svnRepository
```

It is necessary to switch the working copy after the above command and commit the changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-r` option identifies the revision to be copied.  I think you don't need to provide that.

I shall suggest your script doing:

1. `svn commit`
2. `svn copy c:\workingCopy http://example.com/svnrepo/proj/tags/proj-x.y.z`

Comment: the answer: svn copy c:\workingCopy http://svnRepository, no need to commit first I only want the changes in the tag revision not where the working copy came from. thanks.